# NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Validateable)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activemerchant, rails-3-upgrade, shopify-activemerchant

I have integrated `gem 'activemerchant', '1.50.0'` in rails 4 application. In one of class I have included the `ActiveMerchant::Validateable`.

```
class Address
  include ActiveMerchant::Validateable
  attr_accessor :address1, :address2, :city, :state, :zip, :country, :first_name, :last_name, :phone
end
```

It gives me `NameError (uninitialized constant ActiveMerchant::Validateable)` error. This work fine with rails 3.2.13. Is anyone faced this issue.

Comment: What version of active_utils are you running?

Comment: active_utils (3.3.7)